# How can I have my .vimrc detect what OS I'm using?

Tags: vim, vi

Since I upgraded my Ubuntu to version 14 I've had a lot of problems with sharing my .vimrc file between Ubuntu and OSX.

The following commands no longer work and in fact gives errors:

```
set filetype off
match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
```

How can I add a "if Ubuntu" (or "if not OSX") to do these commands in my.vimrc ?

Comment: [See if this helps](http://superuser.com/a/194718)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One options is to use:

```
if system("uname") == "Linux"
  set filetype off
  match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
endif
```

Comment: Code snippet doesn't work, use `=~`. The string returned from the system call has a newline.